# select two databases from different server on single page in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using two different server and make connections in this page but getting data from only one server table. Can you please help me fetch data from both servers? Thanks in advance. How can I select two databases from different servers on single page in PHP?

```
     <?php
      $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "trtxxxxxxxxxxdfg", "dfcxxxxxxxxxxfg");
            mysql_select_db("xxxx", $conn);
$con2=mysql_connect("localhost","hi*********r","h*********7");
         $db2=mysql_select_db("xzcxc", $con2); 
         $sql="select * from bids";
        $exe=mysql_query($sql);
        $rw=mysql_fetch_array($exe);
        echo $rw['bidname'];
        echo "</br>";
        $sql2="select * from wp_cities";
        $exe2=mysql_query($sql2);
        $rw2=mysql_fetch_array($exe2);
        echo "test".$rw2['city']; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you have a query that needs to read data from two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1 pass the first link identifier:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2 pass the second:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

i hope it will be helpful